# You have to build a dictionary (Or any other container of your choice) . Using python

Tags: python-3.x

You have to build a dictionary (Or any other container of your choice) which contains multiple True/false type quiz questions.

Every participant/user will attempt 5 rounds and in each round random quiz questions will be displayed to the user/participant.

If the participant answers the quiz question correct, then congratulate him and add the scores.

At the end display the details and score of the participant.

I have tried but I am not getting expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it can be useful for you. There are many other ways to do it but i think in this way you can understand easier what the script is doing.

```
import requests
import random
import numbers

def get_quiz_questions():
  response = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json')
  if response.status_code != 200:
    return [
        ["The Mars Rover \"Spirit\" is powered by six small motors the size of \"C\" batteries. It has a top speed of 0.1 mph.", True],
        ["Burt Reynolds was originally cast to be Han Solo in the first Star Wars film. He dropped out before filming.", True]
        ]
  return response.json()

# Get questions
quiz_questions = get_quiz_questions()

# Get numeric value, retry if it's not valid.
def get_numeric_value(message):
  print(message)
  value = input()

  if not(value and value.isnumeric()):
    print('Entered value is not valid\n')
    # using recursion to prompt again for a valid value
    return get_numeric_value(message)

  return int(value)

def request_boolean_answer():
  print('Enter answer: [ 0: false |  1: true]')
  answer = input()

  # Check if the value entered is numeric and if it's not 1 or 0
  if answer.isnumeric() and ( 0 != int(answer) != 1):
    print('Entered answer is not valid\n')
    # using recursion 
    return request_boolean_answer()

  return bool(answer)

# Start Game
num_players = get_numeric_value('\nEnter number of players: ')
num_questions = get_numeric_value('\nEnter number of questions: ')

score = {}
for player in range(num_players):
  print("\nPlayer #:", player )

  # initialize score for current user
  score[f'player_{player}'] = 0

  for question in range(num_questions):
    question, answer = random.choice(quiz_questions)
    print(question)

    user_answer = request_boolean_answer()
    print(f'Your answer: {user_answer}, correct answer:  {answer}\n')

    # Add a point if the answer is correct
    if answer == user_answer:
      score[f'player_{player}']+=1
    

print(f'\nScore: {score}')
```